# How to show text within icon

Tags: css, icons

I am new to web development (and self taught) so please excuse if this is a dumb question.

How do I show text inside an icon? Such as number inside a heart etc.
I assuming for this purpose webfont icon will not work?
Is using CSS shapes is better for thus purpose - so that it will render when resized etc?
Or is vector better option.

Here is the CSS for heart that I was planning to use. But I am not clear as how to display text inside.

```
    .heart {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 90px;
    }
    .heart:before,
    .heart:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 50px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
        background: #fc2e5a;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
           -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
             -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
                transform-origin: 0 100%;
    }
    .heart:after {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
           -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
            -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
             -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
                trans.orm-origin :100% 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried overlaying the text using a div with a higher z-order setting in CSS?

Comment: Thanks mbratch - yes I have used z-order. But I was not sure if I combined text and png then how well it work on resize. I thought that if I could embed text inside the CSS shape, that'll be great. But the content property does not quite do it! It displays the number twice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dPaYS/2/) is my solution

I inserted a `span` between the `div` tags. That way, like mbratch said, you can set the `z-index` property as a higher value. This, along with `position:absolute`, will give you what you are looking for.

I used jQuery to vertically center it, in case you wanted multiple lines of text

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the suggestion - I will use this solution, and tweek it to center in the middle!

Comment: Thanks Cody. I have accepted the answer. I do not yet have enough points to upvote.